# R - Get Common Columns without the use of Joins or Merge

Tags: r

I have two data frames in R

```
df1 = data.frame(Cust = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), ItemId = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2))
df2 = data.frame(ItemId1 = c(1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4), ItemId2 = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5))
> df1
   Cust ItemId
1     1      1
2     1      2
3     1      3
4     1      4
5     2      2
6     2      3
7     2      2
8     2      5
9     3      1
10    3      2
11    3      5
12    4      6
13    4      2

> df2
   ItemId1 ItemId2
1        1       3
2        3       1
3        2       2
4        3       3
5        2       4
6        1       1
7        2       6
8        3       4
9        4       2
10       6       4
11       5       3
12       3       1
13       2       3
14       4       5
```

All I need is the following output which is less costly than joins/merge (because in real time I am dealing with billions of records)

```
> output
   ItemId1 ItemId2 Cust
1        1       3    1
2        3       1    1
3        2       2    1, 2, 3, 4
4        3       3    1, 2
5        2       4    1
6        1       1    1, 3
7        2       6    4
8        3       4    1
9        4       2    1
10       6       4    NA
11       5       3    2
12       3       1    1
13       2       3    1, 2
14       4       5    NA
```

What happens is If `ItemId1`, `ItemId2` of `df2` combination is present in `ItemId` of `df1` we need to return the `Cust` values (even if they are multiple). If they are present we need to return `NA`.

i.e. Take the first row as example: `ItemId1 = 1`, `ItemId2 = 3`. Only `Customer = 1` has ItemId = c(1,3) in `df1`. Similarly the next rows.

We can do this using Joins/Merge which are costly operations. But, they are resulting in Memory Error.

Comment: If you're working with billions of records, is your data already in SQL? `dplyr` has nice utilities for interfacing between the two.

Comment: No, my data is in an extracted csv.

Comment: Still not clear how do you get Customer Id's in output

Comment: Take the first row as example: ItemId1 = 1, ItemId2 = 3. Only Customer = 1 has ItemId = c(1,3) in `df1`. Similarly the next rows. You got it or you need me to elaborate even more?

Comment: What's the point of having duplicate rows in `df2`? Should rows `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` produce the same `Cust`? What's the point of rows where `ItemId1==ItemId2`? What let you think that this is less expensive than a `merge`?

Comment: Did you try using `data.table` instead of `data.frame`? Usually it is by far faster, and don't requires as much memory.

Comment: @nicola I have given my sample dataset in that way, In real time its a transaction details table where customer bought 2 items (in the order of bill submission). So, there are high chances of `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` and for `ItemId1 == ItemId2` the customer has bought the same item twice.

Comment: @CarlosAlberto - I haven't worked much on `data.table`. What could be the possible methods in `data.table` that resolves my issue?

Comment: `data.table` makes joins and merges really fast, and keeps only one copy of your info in the memory. so, you should be able to translate the code you already have (pretty much the same functions in most of the cases) and speed it up a lot. some things may require some rewriting and the data.table codes are very concise but a bit hard to get at the beginning. Usually R loops are not as efficient as codes running internally, which are optimized and run on C most of the time.

Comment: btw... if you figure it out, post your answer. I'm really interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

This may take more time but wont take much of your memory.
Please convert for loops using apply if possible:

```
library(plyr)
df1 = data.frame(Cust = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), ItemId = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2))
df2 = data.frame(ItemId1 = c(1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 4), ItemId2 = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5))
temp2 = ddply(df1[,c("Cust","ItemId")], .(Cust), summarize, ItemId = toString(unique(ItemId)))
temp3 = ddply(df1[,c("ItemId","Cust")], .(ItemId), summarize, Cust = toString(unique(Cust)))
dfout = cbind(df2[0,],data.frame(Cust = df1[0,1]))
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
    a = df2[i,1]
    b = df2[i,2]
    if(a == b){
        dfout = rbind(dfout,data.frame(ItemId1 = a,ItemId2 = a,Cust = temp3$Cust[temp3$ItemId == a]))
    }else{
        cusli = c()
        for(j in 1:nrow(temp2)){

            if(length(grep(a,temp2$ItemId[j]))>0 & length(grep(b,temp2$ItemId[j]))>0){
                cusli = c(cusli,temp2$Cust[j])
            }
        }
        dfout = rbind(dfout,data.frame(ItemId1 = a,ItemId2 = b,Cust = paste(cusli,collapse = ", ")))
    }
}
dfout$Cust[dfout$Cust == "",] = NA
```

Comment: This works, but is impractical for data of the size in question, even translated to `*apply`.